# Error EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386)

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a run time error:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I1386_BPT,subcode=0x0).

Debugger shows: 0 swift_dynamiCastClassUnconditional
```

My code crash here..

```
override func prepareForSegue ( segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "solveBar") {
        var svcBar = segue.destinationViewController as BarTableViewController2
```

Can i have some advice?

Comment: You need to include the relevant code with your question. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

try by pressing cmnd + 7 and deleting all the breakpoints

Comment: There is no breakpoint inside the code. I did pressed cmd + 7 to double check, but error still persist after that...